# vlcj embeddedmediaplayercomponent in Jinternal Fream Adding Issues

Tags: swing, jinternalframe, vlcj

**Jinternal** frame Add **jvlcEmbeddedmediaPlayerComponent** problem is **jDropdownlist** open than list  is  back side list in vlc Control and other Problem is if maximize Jinternal Frame other vlc Component our Spreed  Current Maximize jinternal frame look like Same thing jDropdown Control behavior.

How to Fix the Problems.
below Attach Image

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to overlay a lightweight Swing component on top of a heavyweight AWT Canvas.

Use:

```
JPopupMenu.setDefaultLightWeightPopupEnabled(false);
```

This is what the example media player provided by vlcj does:

https://github.com/caprica/vlcj/blob/vlcj-3.0.1/src/test/java/uk/co/caprica/vlcj/test/basic/TestPlayer.java